# What does "content writing" mean?

Tags: phrase-meaning, phrase-usage, phrases, collocations

Isn't the phrase "content writing" weird? Why do we have the word "content" here? Isn't it obvious when we say "writing"?

Comment: One could be writing simply for practice, without creating content. One might also be transcribing without creating content.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is an example of [jargon](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jargon), originally from the publishing and media industries, which has now been adopted across the internet.  In media, **content** is material that is intended for the consumer. Content is not just writing - it could be video or photography or anything like that - and the general term for producing this material is [**content creation**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Content_creation).

More recently, [**content**](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/content) has come to mean, "the principal substance (such as written matter, illustrations, or music) offered by a website."

So **content writing** is more specific than just **writing**.  Even if you work for a website or a media company, you could be writing emails or legal contracts or corporate policies, all of which is writing without being content writing.  But if you're doing **content writing**, then you're writing material for publication, and it's one form of **content creation** (you may be partnered with a graphic designer who does **content illustration**, for example).

Answer (score -1):

A Google search brings up this result at the top of the page: (You could easily have checked this yourself!)

**Content writing is the process of planning, writing and editing web content, typically for digital marketing purposes. It can include writing blog posts and articles, scripts for videos and podcasts, as well as content for specific platforms, such as tweet-storms on Twitter or text posts on Reddit.**

Phrases are what they are! Weirdness or otherwise doesn't come into it.

https://www.google.com/search?client=firefox-b-d&q=content+writing